# rails 3.1, capybara-webkit, why page.execute_script fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, capybara, capybara-webkit

After installing capybara-webkit, I tried to try a test inside a spec, here is my test:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :webkit

page.execute_script("$('#submit_direction').attr('value', '1');$('#quizForm').submit()")
```

Then, I get this error:

> /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136:
>   warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/sam/Documents/RoR in PATH,
>   mode 040777 undefined|0|ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
>
> Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError: Javascript
>   failed to execute

Any idea please ?

Comment: Could you provide more details for your step? I think you can see issue for this step because of undefined jQuery on the page in the moment when you try to run this step. May be you should make it on window load event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing the capybara-webkit JS driver is a bit dodgy.

From the [capybara github page](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara):

> For simple expressions, you can return the result of the script. Note
>   that this may break with more complicated expressions:
>
> result = page.evaluate_script('4 + 4');

However, from the code you have there, it looks like you can do quite a few things with Capybara itself.

```
$('#submit_direction').attr('value', '1')
```

could be replaced with:

```
page.find("#submit_direction").set('1')
```

and

```
$('#quizForm').submit()
```

could be replaced with:

```
page.click_on('quizForm')
```

see the capybara [docs on capybara actions](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried page.click_on('quizForm'), but I have no button for the form with 'quizForm' value, instead, I submit it with js in the link, is it possible to submit the form with capybara without using the form button ? or, how to hide the button and still be visible to capybara ?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I've managed to render the submit button only while testing:
- if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "test"
    %div
      = submit_tag 'Submit Answer'
so that I can depend on the submit button only while testing, thanks!